# Is it possible to create an iPad compatible iPhone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I remember a while ago, iPhone/iPod apps could be downloaded on to an iPad and scaled up to fit the screen. I want to make an iPhone and iPad compatible app however my iPhone storyboard doesn't translate well into an iPad storyboard, so is it possible to release my app for iPhone and iPad, by just scaling the interface on iPads?

Answer (score 2):

You want to make it a [universal app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iPhone-only app, then it will automatically run on iPads, either small in the middle of the screen or scaled up to fill most (but not all) of the screen. So if all you're looking for on iPad is your exact iPhone interface scaled up, then make sure your app is iPhone-only.

If you do wish to have a different interface on iPad at all, especially if you want it to actually fill the screen, you'll need to make your app universal, and create a separate iPad storyboard. You can either copy your view controllers over from your iPhone storyboard, or you can create them new in the iPad storyboard, it just depends on how similar you want them. If you were going for a radically different iPad interface, you would probably create new ones. In fact your iPad interface and navigation won't necessarily correspond to the iPhone version (although generally they do correspond pretty closely, it's just that the iPad usually shows more at once, or has some kind of navigation that remains visible all of the time).